# In F#, can a record type be made public when in a module within a Namespace?

Tags: f#

In F#, a record type placed directly in a Namespace will be compiled as a class type for C#.

```
e.g., 
namespace MyNameSpace
type MyType  = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
```

MyType will be seen as a static public class by C#.

But how does C# see MyType when it is in a module within a namespace?

```
e.g.,
 namespace MyNameSpace
 module MyModule
    type MyType  = { Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
```

If it is private to MyModule, can it be made public for C#?

(I could not find this answer with Google :( )

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An F# module is compiled as a class. If you have a type declaration inside a module, it will be compiled as a nested class. In your example of `MyNameSpace.MyModule.MyType`, the `MyNameSpace` part is a namespace, but `MyModule` (and also `MyType`) are classes.

In C#, you access nested classes using `.`, but at the CLR level, a nested class is accessed using `+`, so if you want to access `MyType` for example using `Type.GetType`, you need to use:

```
System.Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyModule+MyType")
```

Note that this does not work in F# Interactive, which adds another name to the namespace, but it works in compiled code. I'm not sure how `DataTemplate` in WPF works, but it's possible you need to specify the type using the CLR format with `+` in the name.

Answer (score 1):

By default I believe all module members will follow the same public static declaration form. Compiling your example here results in an easily accessible MyType class from C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new MyNameSpace.MyModule.MyType("x", "b", "c");
}
```

In order to *force* access control of a module member, you need to tweak the declaration slightly:

```
module MySecrets =
    type private SecretType = { Password: string }
```

EDIT: Aha, found the relevant page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/access-control

Comment: I though so too.  However, when the MyType is used in a DataTemplate of WPF/C#,  as DataType="{x:Type vm:MyType}" works with vm being a pointer to the namespace. But, DataType="{x:Type vm:MyModule.MyType}" consistently fails in the CLR saying it can not find MyType. This maybe due to the WPF CLR??? Anyway, it seems it needs to be in the namespace.

Comment: Records can be put in modules and consumed by C# clients.
The module name is part of qualified path when accessing the record.
Example: open my_namespace_path.my_module.

Comment: @ScottNimrod  Maybe so for C# clients--not so much for wpf/xaml. It seems only F# records directly in the namespace are being seen by the CLR. I have not been successfully placing the record within a module that is itself within a namespace :(

Comment: I build mobile apps using F# with Xamarin.Forms which is also XAML.
I think that there's a different problem that you're experiencing.

Comment: Have you considered using the static import of the class name in your code behind files?

Example: using static mynamespece.mymodule